# Select only months which have data for a specified Year

Tags: sql

I would like a query which selects only those month's which have data for a specified year but I'm not quite sure how to achieve this. Here is what I have got so far:

```
select MONTH(DateRaised) as 'Month'
from Complaints
where
    (select COUNT(*)
     from Complaints
     where YEAR(DateRaised) = 2000) > 0
group by MONTH(dateraised)
order by MONTH(dateraised)
```

So if my data had a Complaint from May, August and December in 2000, then I would only like `5, 8 and 12` to appear in my query, is this possible?

Comment: The answers show that the query is simpler than you thought. But, in general, rather than doing a `COUNT(*)` and comparing it to `0`, you ought to use `EXISTS()` instead. Some (rather stupid) SQL systems will count all of the records, whereas `EXISTS()` will almost always complete as soon as it finds a single matching row.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I was over-thinking it! Thanks for the tip regarding `EXISTS()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select DISTINCT MONTH(DateRaised) AS 'Month'
from Complaints
where YEAR(DateRaised) = 2000
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select MONTH(DateRaised) as 'Month'
from Complaints
where YEAR(DateRaised) = 2000
ORDER BY MONTH(dateraised)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MONTH(DateRaised) as 'Month', COUNT(*) AS count
FROM Complaints
WHERE YEAR(DateRaised) = 2000
GROUP BY MONTH(dateraised)
ORDER BY MONTH(dateraised)
```